# How can I match things like "C#" and "C++" in PostgreSQL's full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Unfortunately the parser discards all punctuation, so that 'C', 'C++' and 'C#' all end up as 'c'.

The only thing I can think of (aside from replacing the parser which isn't really an option right now), would be to implement my own miniature synonym dictionary before using any of the FTS functions, replacing "C++" with "Cpp" and "C#" with "Csharp" either in the application or in the queries, for example. Is there any way to do this with FTS functions/features?

Comment: you could try html encoding the values before storing them.  how does it handle C%2b%2b ?

Comment: Since the parser creates new tokens at any punctuation, that's no better: where "C++" is broken into three tokens ("C", "+" and "+", the last two of which are ignored by the dictionary), "C%2b%2b" is broken into "C", "%", "2b", "%" and "2b".

That said, since the "2b"s would make it through, that would kinda work...

Answer (score 4):

The dictionary search filters out a number of symbols (spaces, punctuation) and irrelevant words (aka stopwords: a, the…). However, some programming languages contain one or the other, or even both!

To overcome this, we need to create a custom thesaurus, bring it to the attention of PostgreSQL, link it to a dictionary that is also customised because it must not be aware of stopwords, and finally alter the configuration for ASCII characters and symbols.

Our thesaurus should be located in `/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/` and we will name it `prog_thesaurus.ths`. It'll look like this:

```
c + + : cplusplus
c # : csharp
. net : dotnet
f # : fsharp
```

Notice the spaces between the words and symbols!

Now we need to create a custom dictionary without stopwords. It will be based on the english one:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_nostop_stem (
    TEMPLATE = snowball,
    Language = english
);
```

Then we tell PostgreSQL about our thesaurus:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY prog_thesaurus (
    TEMPLATE = thesaurus,
    DictFile = prog_thesaurus,
    Dictionary = english_nostop_stem
);
```

Finally, we must map our thesaurus with some token types. Here we'll map asciiword (`c`, `f`, `net`, etc.) and blank (`+`, `#`, `.`, etc.):

```sql
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, blank
    WITH prog_thesaurus, english_stem;
```

If we test our new configuration:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english', 'c++');
   alias   |   description   | token |         dictionaries         | dictionary  | lexemes 
-----------+-----------------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | c     | {prog_thesaurus,english_stem} | english_stem | {}
 blank     | Space symbols   | +     | {prog_thesaurus,english_stem} | english_stem | {+}
 blank     | Space symbols   | +     | {prog_thesaurus,english_stem} | english_stem | {+}
(3 lignes)
```

Yay! Our thesaurus is used! And with a little query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM plainto_tsquery('english','c++');
 plainto_tsquery
-----------------
 'cplusplus'
(1 ligne)
```

Tada! `c++` is found as an occurrence of `cplusplus`.

Answer (score 3):

you can create thesaurus dictionary with lines

```
c + + : cpp
c # : csharp
```

and then add mapping for text search configuration for "blank" token type with your new dictionary mentioned first

Comment: could you explain this a little more. I'm not sure this is actually working. How can this be tested and what is the expected output? I would expect `SELECT * FROM plainto_tsquery('english','c#');` to return csharp, but it doesn't. I'm using [this blog post](http://sharingtechknowledge.blogspot.com/2012/02/postgresql-thesaurus-dictionary.html) as a guide, but changing the mapping to use blank `ALTER MAPPING FOR blank WITH programming_ths`

Answer (score 1):

Transliterate any relevant punctuation to words. C++ -> Cplusplus, C# -> Csharp, PL/SQL -> PLslashSQL